# progress bar for a process pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm making a simple pyqt code where I have a button which calls a shell command. I would like to add a progress bar for the execution of the shell command. Do you have an idea how to link the progress bar and the process (shell command) ?

```
    def dataReady(self):
        cursorOutput = self.output.textCursor()
        cursorOutput.movePosition(cursorOutput.End)

        # Read stdout from child process
        processStdout = str(self.process.readAll())

        # Update self.output
        cursorOutput.insertText(processStdout)

        self.output.ensureCursorVisible()


    def startProcess(self):
        self.completed = 0

        while self.completed < 100:
            self.completed += 0.0001
            self.progress.setValue(self.completed)

        script = f"""cd /Users/alex/test/src; ./Allmake_all;"""
        self.process.start("bash", ["-c", script])


    def initUI(self):
        # Elements
        self.progress = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self)
        self.startBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Install all',self)
        self.startBtn.clicked.connect(self.startProcess)
        self.output = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
```

Comment: That depends on the script that you execute, for example if the script scans 100 images then your script should notify each time it scans an image and at that moment update the progressbar but in your case it is not possible to do that analysis since you do not provide that code of the script

Comment: Hi , thanks for the help, normally my code would call a command that install programs such as openfoam.

Comment: Does that installation notify the progress on the console?